# How to make view extension that applies modifiers to it self and also takes in content?

Tags: swift, swiftui

I have following pattern that I repeat often throughout my app, so am trying to make it a view extension i.e. (note that `someCondition` is not always present, it can be just a plain view as well)

```
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
      if someCondition {
        SomeView()
      }
    }
```

so far I tried something like this

```
func footer<Content: View>(content: View) -> some View {
  self
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
      content
    }
}
```

But using it like this, yields various errors

```
VStack {}
  .footer {
     // any valid view code
  }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`footer` should take a function type `() -> Content`, since you want to pass in a closure. The parameter should also be a `@ViewBuilder`, so that you can write the `if` statement like that.

```
// in a View extension...
func footer<Content: View>(@ViewBuilder content: () -> Content) -> some View {
  self
    .edgesIgnoringSafeArea(.bottom)
    .safeAreaInset(edge: .bottom) {
      content()
    }
}
```